# Call Receive Ether Function from Brownie

Tags: solidity, brownie

Please, how to make a transaction from Brownie to a smart contract which has a receive function like so:

```
address payable public destination;
event ForwarderDeposited(address from, uint256 value, bytes data);

receive() external payable {
    destination.transfer(msg.value);
    emit ForwarderDeposited(msg.sender, msg.value, msg.data);
}
```

In, for example some test that could look like:

```
def test_recieve():
    # Arrange
    account = accounts[0]
    sender = accounts[1]
    # Act
    forwarder = Forwarder.deploy({"from": account})
    txn = forwarder.receive(5, {"from": sender})
    txn.wait(1)
    # Assert
    assert forwarder.destination().balance() == 5
```

Throws error: `AttributeError: Contract 'Forwarder' object has no attribute 'receive'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call your `receive` function from brownie, you have to use:

```
sender.transfer(to=forwarder, amount=5)
```

Also please note that you can't have `msg.data` with `receive` fallback function: [see documentation here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function)

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks! Just for anyone not to get confused, use like this: `sender.transfer(forwarder, "1 ether")`